# css positioning tables next to each other

Tags: html, css, positioning

Using the HTML/CSS below I have 3 tables.
I would like table 1 and 2 to be next to each other on the "same line" with table 3 underneath but with a break between them.

However, when I use float:left/right on the first two tables, table 3 is ALWAYS directly underneath and "touching" tables1/2?

I have tried margin/clear/float and can't seem to make things line up :(

Any help gratefully received.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        DIV.search
        {
            width: 80%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        DIV.search TABLE
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: separate;
        }

        DIV.search TABLE.table1
        {
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
        }

        DIV.search TABLE.table2
        {
            float: right;
            width: 45%;
        }

        TABLE.table3
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search">
        <table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TABLE 1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TABLE 2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table class="table3">
        <tr>
            <td>
                TABLE 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your posted code seems fine to me in chrome.  There is room between the tables... http://jsfiddle.net/uJtFy/  which browser are you using?

Comment: What's wrong with your current one? I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4sCj/) and it works fine in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Not sure why jsFiddle shows the room between the tables, if you create the page and open it in Chrome it is as BlueChippy is describing.

Comment: Hmm...sounds like a browser issue then?  I've tried FireFox and IE8 and its the same (screwed!) in both.  Target browser will be IE8 as this is the standard in the company it's for.

Comment: Perhaps I should re-phrase the question:  I'd like two tables side by side, with a further table underneath them.  Don't care how!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply some additional styles:

```
DIV.search
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

    overflow: hidden; /* Fixing the problem in modern browsers */
    zoom: 1; /* Fixing in old IE by applying hasLayout */
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* I prefer padding here than margin in table3 */
}

TABLE.table3
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* margin-top: 50px; */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

You can try to use :after (in the answer below), but old IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late but a similar solution may be to but in the css "`display:inline-block`" but there is also "`display:inline-table`". Worked for me :)

Also, an additional thing working for me was using `"float:left"`

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/45zMz/1/)

Comment: It may be late, but this is an excellent answer! It saved my exact problem in webkit browser trying to position many small tables on a single row. Thanks!