# How to render 2 html tables next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to render 2 tables next to each other horizontally like this:

|Table 1|     |Table 2|
|---------|   |----------|
|---------|   |----------|
|---------|   |----------|

**What is proper way to do that?**

---

Currently, I got this html:

```
<div style="vertical-align:top;">
 <table style="display:inline-table;">
  ...1st table
 </table>
 <table  style="display:inline-table;">
  ...2nd table
 </table>
</div>
```

Having troubles with vertical alignment, it renders out like this (table#2 has 1 less row):

|Table 1|
|---------|   |Table 2|
|---------|   |----------|
|---------|   |----------|

I would like it to start from top.

P.s. There is [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548880/css-positioning-tables-next-to-each-other), but I don't want to wrap it around w/ divs.

Comment: Have you tried `float: left;` ?

Comment: @Ziga did try it, it ends up being far away to the right and under first table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top` or using `float: left` instead of `display:inline-table`.

Comment: vertical-align didn't work. but float:left worked. will accept after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need them to be 2 separate tables? Could you not use table columns instead

e.g.

Table

Col 1    Col 2

|--------|--------|

|--------|--------|

|--------|--------|

|--------|--------|

otherwise have both tables using this CSS code:

```
float: left;
display: inline-block;
```